# Sum of 1 to 1000 when we write all continuous and clear zero digits and instead of this set space?

Tags: algorithm, math, recursion

Can you help me for find algorithm(math formula) for this question?
For example :

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 -> f(1)= 1 + 2 + .. + 8 + 9 + 1

1 2 3 .. 98 99 100 -> f(2)= 1 + 2 + .. + 8 + 9 + 1(1+0) + 11 + 12 + … + 99 + 1

1 2 3 .. 98 99 100 … 998 999 1000 -> f(3)= 1 + 2 + .. + 8 + 9 + 1 + 11 + 12 + … + 99 + 1 + 2 + .. + 111 + … + 1
```

NOTICE : `102 change to : 1 2 (1+0+2=3)`
Rather be recursive!

Comment: Where does this puzzle come from?

Comment: I do not understand at all what you are asking. What does "1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10" mean? Are you adding those numbers? And so on.

Comment: @rici Um.. I don't know! it's just mathematical problem!

Comment: @RoryDaulton I want to write a function that if give this 1 it return me 1 + 2 + .. + 8 + 9 + 1!   and this answer actually is 1+2+3+4+5+6+7+8+9+1(1 + 0)

Comment: @mohsen: OK, I don't do programming or math contests unless I know the source. So good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 + 6 + 7 + 8 + 1 + 11 + ... + n
=
  (1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 + 6 + 7 + 8 + 10 + 11 + ... + n)
- (10 + 20 + ... + n)                                       { remove numbers ending in 0 }
+ (1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 + 6 + 7 + 8 + 9 + 1 + 11 + ... + n/10) { add back in numbers with their 0's removed }
```

This gives a nice simple algorithm:

```
f :: Integer -> Integer
f 0 = 0
f n =      n  * (n +1) `div` 2 -- famous Euler formula
    - 10 * n' * (n'+1) `div` 2 -- subtract the multiples of 10
    + f n'
    where n' = n `div` 10
```

For example, we can see it run in ghci:

```
> mapM_ print [(n, f n) | n <- [9, 10, 11, 99, 100, 101]]
(9,45)
(10,46)
(11,57)
(99,4545)
(100,4546)
(101,4647)
```

It recurses only log(n) times, doing O(1) arithmetic operations at each recursion, so does O(log(n)) arithmetic operations total. (Indeed, it's a small enough computation that you could feasibly do it by hand for the first 1000 terms if you wanted.)

Comment: Thanks! but I think you forget this : 102 changed to 1 + 0 + 2 ! but you just process numbers that ending with zero!

Comment: @Mohsen I see. I did not understand that part of the problem. That makes things significantly less natural!

Comment: @Daniel: since the original problem seems to only be asking for the sums of ranges [1...10^k] for integer k, a reasonably simple and fairly natural recursion does exist. That's a basis for a general solution, of sorts.

Comment: @rici Nice hint! You have transmitted the solution to my mind -- and I think the motivated reader, with some thought, will be able to come up with it, too. =)